# Can I check whether a certain widget has certain option

Tags: wordpress, widget, wordpress-theming

Say I have a widget called Foo. This widget has some options like title, image field, checkbox etc. I have to enqueu some scripts in head or just after opening body tag if the widget has certain title or checkbox selected. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the value of widget instance scripts can be enqueued to footer not in head or just after body tag. Reason behind this is the instance value can be checked inside the function `widget` of widget class. The function `widget` is called when a certain dynamic sidebar is called and this must occurs when `wp_head()` and `wp_body_open` hook is already fired but still there is a chance to enqueue scripts to footer.